# ASP.NET Filling in textfields in Gridview from session variables for ShoppingCart

Tags: asp.net

In my gridview I list of bunch of products from database which is loaded by a Stored Procedure.
So in the gridview I list i.e. Product Name, Price, Description etc but then I have a textfield called quantity where the user can enter in a quantity and when they press update I then insert this as a cartitem in my shoppingcart

```
Protected Sub btnUpdateCart_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdateCart.Click
    For Each row As GridViewRow In gvShoppingCart.Rows
        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            ' We'll use a try catch block in case something other than a number is typed in. If so, we'll just ignore it.
            Try
                ' Get the productId from the GridView's datakeys
                Dim productId = Convert.ToInt32(gvShoppingCart.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value)
                ' Find the quantity TextBox and retrieve the value
                Dim quantity = Integer.Parse(CType(row.Cells(1).FindControl("txtQuantity"), TextBox).Text)
                ShoppingCart.Instance.SetItemQuantity(productId, quantity)
            Catch ex As FormatException
            End Try
        End If
    Next

    BindData()
End Sub
```

As such but then when I flick between the pages and i.e. shoppingcart.aspx and checkout.aspx I loose the values entered in those checkboxes, so what I am looking to do is everytime I load the page with the gridview is to check for my session shoppingcart and see if product id matches between row and session and if they do then enter that quantity dynamically back in textbox. heres my gridview

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvShoppingCart" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="There is nothing in your shopping cart." AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="tr_dark"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="header_req" BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="25" AllowSorting="false" Width="100%" ShowFooter="true" DataKeyNames="ProductId" OnRowDataBound="gvShoppingCart_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gvShoppingCart_RowCommand">

    <Columns>                         
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Name" HeaderStyle-Width="130px" SortExpression="productName">
                <ItemTemplate>   
                <asp:Label ID="ProductNameField" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("description").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>                     
            </asp:TemplateField> 

    </Columns>
    <Columns>                         
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pack Size" HeaderStyle-Width="70px" SortExpression="packSize">
                <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:Label ID="PackSizeField" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("packSize").ToString()%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>                     
            </asp:TemplateField> 

    </Columns>
    <Columns>                         
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stock" HeaderStyle-Width="130px" SortExpression="address">
                <ItemTemplate>   
                <asp:Label ID="TradePriceField" runat="server" Text='<%#   DisplayStockLevel(Eval("StockIndicator").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>                     
            </asp:TemplateField> 

    </Columns>
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" HeaderStyle-Width="10px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server"  Width="30" ID="txtQuantity" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="Actual Price" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalPrice" HeaderText="Total" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
    </Columns>
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton  ImageUrl="~/img/icons/cross.gif"  width="10" height="10" alt="Cancel" runat="server" ID="btnRemove" CommandName="Remove" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductId") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate class of products (c# code):

```
public class CartProducts
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalUnits { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public ProductImages ProductImage { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalItemPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return Price * TotalUnits * Quantity;
        }
    }

    private string _productDesc;
    public string ProductDesc
    {
        get
        {
            return (_productDesc.Length > 100) ? _productDesc.Substring(0, 100) + "...." : _productDesc;
        }
        set
        {

            _productDesc = value;
        }
    }
}
```

When you get your products from SP , create a list of wrapper cart products on the top of the list returned by your stored procedure, Store the list of your wrapper class in Session

lets assume your SP name is "GetallProducts"

```
var products = dbContext.GetallProducts();
List<CartProducts> products = (from prods in products select new CartProducts{
ID = prods.ID ,
ProductName = prods.Name,
Price = prods.Price,
TotalUnits = prods.TotalUnits

}).ToList();
```

Now create a separate class which will handle all the Shopping cart operations, something like this:

```
public class Cart
{

    private List<CartProducts> _cartProducts;
    public List<CartProducts> cartProducts
    {
        get
        {
            _cartProducts = SessionService.PullFromSession<List<CartProducts>>        (SessionKeys.Cart);
            if (_cartProducts == null)
            {
                _cartProducts = new List<CartProducts>();
            }
            return _cartProducts;
        }
        set
        {
            _cartProducts = value;

            SessionService.PushToSession(SessionKeys.Cart, _cartProducts);
        }
    }

    public decimal TotalPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return cartProducts.Sum(p => p.TotalItemPrice);
        }
    }


    public void UpdateProduct(int quantity, int productID)
    {
       //Update logic here


    }



    public long PlaceOrder()
    {
        //Place order

    }
}
```

Now bind your grid with the list of products which is in session like this:
     private void BindCart()
        {
            //Cart Object

```
        Cart c = new Cart();
        if (c.cartProducts.Count > 0)
        dlistCart.DataSource = c.cartProducts;
        dlistCart.DataBind();

    }
```

Now each time you update your item in cart use something like this:

```
var txtQuantity = e.Item.FindControl("txtQuantity") as TextBox;
        if (e.CommandName == "update")
        {

            if (txtQuantity != null)
            {
                if (txtQuantity.Text.isInt())
                {
                    var count = txtQuantity.Text.toInt();
                    int ProductID = e.CommandArgument.ToString().toInt();

                    Cart cart = new Cart();
                    cart.UpdateProduct(count, ProductID);
                }
            }
        }
```

Sorry this all code is in C# as i don't know VB , and i recently worked on a shopping cart and pasting code from that, but logic will remain the same.

hope this helps

Comment: Can you explain how I can create the wrapper of products from the result set of SP ?

Comment: i will explain in my post above